# Related Rates Question Concerning Gay Lussac's Law

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Gay Lussac's Law for enclosed gases states that if the volume is kept constant, the pressure $P$ and temperature $T$ are related by the equation $\dfrac{P}{T}=k$, where $k$ is a constant. Suppose that the rate of change of the temperature is $3$ degrees per hour. What is the rate of change of pressure when $T$ is $250$ and $P$ is $500$?

I know this is a related rates question involving differentiation, and that $\dfrac{dT}{dt}=3$ but I just can't figure out how to tie the values together! Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I thought Boyle's law involved pressure and volume (not temperature). But anyway, yes, $\dfrac{dT}{dt}=3$. So start from the given

$$ \dfrac{P}{T}=k$$

So both $P$ and $T$ are functions of time, $t$. $k$ is just a constant. So, differentiating, we need to use the quotient rule:

$$\dfrac{ T \dfrac{dP}{dt} - P \dfrac{dT}{dt}}{T^2} = 0$$.

Along the way you need to understand, why is this equation equated to 0? 
You know that $\dfrac{dT}{dt} = 3$, so the rest must be easy.

Comment: This is indeed very correct but, may be, it could be set simpler since, rewriting the equation, $P$ is proportional to $T$ and then the result.

Comment: I didn't think of that!

Comment: This is the (only) privilege of age ! I can only handle simple things or concepts and, moreover, I am very lazy now ! Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

First of all law you are talking about is not Boyle's law But Gay Lussac's Law.

According to your  question $\frac{P}{T}=k$

And hence $k=\frac{500}{250}=2$. Now Hoping that you have mentioned temperature change in degree centigrade. differentiating both sides wit respect to time gives

$\frac{dP}{dt}=k\frac{dT}{dt}=2 \cdot 3=6$